# Trying to control the feild current of a AC generator with a MOSFET transistor and PWM will this work?

Tags: arduino, mosfet, current, pwm, atmega

[image: AVR (Automatic Voltage Reg.]
Trying to help out a fellow vet. He needs a replacement AVR for a 25KVA 60hz generator.

There is a generator output when I flash the field. I am going to monitor the voltage output to control the field. The generator also has 2 CT's and a shunt trip breaker. I am going to use the CT's to monitor for over current to trip the breaker. I am going to use a ATmega328P micro. to control and monitor voltage, current, oil pres., water temp., and RPM. I should say, I am going to try.

Comment: Driving the field looks quite ok, but you don't imply that there is generator output voltage or current detection. Without this feedback small changes in generator load will result in large changes in voltage output. It's also typical on 25-50 KVA generators to have rectified CT's providing sudden load and overcurrent feedback to stop the generator shutting down when faced with starting an AC motor as load.

Comment: Is it important to only have answers from vets?

Comment: Thank you Jack for the reply. ("Driving the field looks quite ok, but you don't imply that there is generator output voltage or current detection.") There is a generator output when I flash the field. I am going to monitor the voltage output to control the field. The generator also has 2 CT's also and a shunt trip breaker. I am going to use the CT's to monitor for over current to trip the breaker. I am going to use a ATmega328P micro. to control and monitor voltage, current, oil pres., water temp., and RPM. I should say, I am  going to try.

Comment: "Is it important to only have answers from vets? – Andy" No if you have experience and can be of help join in.

Comment: Andy if you can help out then we can have the Amos and Andy comment's. Just a little humor no pun intended.